# Range of convergence for a Gaussian in the complex plane

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, complex-integration

Given the following integral

$$Z(\lambda) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \exp\left( -\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{\lambda}{4!}x^4\right)$$

We want to find for what values of $\lambda$ does this integral converge. If we assume that $\lambda \in \Bbb R$ we see three clear cases to inspect

- $\lambda < 0$

Given that the $x^4$ dominates as $x\to \infty$, we conclude that $Z(\lambda)$ diverges.

- $\lambda = 0$

We simply get the Gaussian integral, so $Z(\lambda)$ converges.

- $\lambda > 0$

Given that the $x^4$ dominates as $x\to \infty$, we see that such term decreases faster that the $x^2$, which we know that converges. So by comparison, we conclude that $Z(\lambda)$ converges.

Hence we determine that $Z(\lambda)$ converges for $\lambda \geq 0$

But what if we assume $\lambda \in \Bbb C$. What cases should we consider? I guess we would follow an analogous procedure but I do not see it...

Comment: A good idea to understand what happens is to consider the modulus of the integrand, which is $e^{-x^2/2} \cdot e^{\ell x^4}$ where $\ell$ is the real part of $\lambda/24$. So if $\ell \geq 0$, the integral remains absolutely convergent. If $\ell < 0$, the modulus goes to $+\infty$ at infinity so the integral will very probably diverge (even conditionally, though that doesn’t look absolutely obvious to me).

Comment: @Mindlack but to be sure for the $\ell < 0$ case, should we evaluate the integral ? Or is there another method to check it?

Comment: I’m not entirely sure tbh. Perhaps make an IBP to study behavior at $+\infty$ by multiplying and dividing by $(-2x-\lambda x^3/6)$. The other integral should be dominated by the  evaluation term.